# Undefined reference with g++4.7.3 and g++4.8?

Tags: c++, c++11, compiler-errors, g++, undefined-reference

Consider this code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

template <typename Type>
struct Constant
{
    constexpr Constant(const Type source) : _data({{source}}) {;}
    constexpr Constant(const std::array<Type, 1> source) : _data(source) {;}
    constexpr Constant<Type> operator()() const {return _data;}
    constexpr operator Type() const {return _data[0];}
    const std::array<Type, 1> _data;
    static constexpr Constant<Type> pi = 3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209749445L;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::cout<<Constant<double>::pi()<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I get a compiler error with `g++4.7.3` and `g++4.8.0` (which is an undefined reference to `pi` (sorry it's in French)) :

```
/tmp/cctdvPfq.o: dans la fonction « main »:
main.cpp:(.text.startup+0xd): référence indéfinie vers « Constant<double>::pi »
collect2: erreur: ld a retourné 1 code d'état d'exécution
```

As my system is a fresh install (first time with `g++4.7.3` and `g++4.8.0`), I do not know whether it comes from my system configuration or from the compiler. If it comes from the compiler, where is the problem ?

EDIT: and why this is working ? (version with no array)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

template <typename Type>
struct Constant
{
    constexpr Constant(const Type source) : _data(source) {;}
    constexpr Constant<Type> operator()() const {return _data;}
    constexpr operator Type() const {return _data;}
    const Type _data;
    static constexpr Constant<Type> pi = 3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209749445L;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::cout<<Constant<double>::pi()<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could avoid invoking the call operator on `pi`, so that it is not **odr-used** by your program, and the compiler can treat `pi` just like a value that can be inlined, thus not requiring a *definition* for that `static` data member:

```
std::cout << Constant<double>::pi << std::endl;
//                             ^^
```

Alternatively, you could keep invoking `pi`'s call operator, and provide a *definition* of your static data member at namespace scope, and use the call operator of `Constant<double>` as in your original code:

```
template <typename Type>
struct Constant
{
    // ...
    static constexpr Constant<Type> pi = /* ... */;
};

template<typename Type>
constexpr Constant<Type> Constant<Type>::pi;
```

Per paragraph 9.4.2/3 of the C++11 Standard:

> If a non-volatile `const` static data member is of integral or enumeration type, its declaration in the class
>   definition can specify a *brace-or-equal-initializer* in which every *initializer-clause* that is an *assignment-expression*
>   is a constant expression (5.19). A static data member of literal type can be declared in the
>   class definition with the `constexpr` specifier; if so, its declaration shall specify a *brace-or-equal-initializer*
>   in which every *initializer-clause* that is an assignment-expression is a constant expression. [ Note: In both
>   these cases, the member may appear in constant expressions. —end note ] **The member shall still be defined
>   in a namespace scope if it is odr-used (3.2) in the program and the namespace scope definition shall not
>   contain an initializer**.

Comment: It works well under g++4.7.2 : I call the `operator()` of the member `pi`.

Comment: @Vincent: But that makes your `pi` odr-used, and you need to provide a namespace-level definition

Comment: @Vincent: Because the array needs to have a location in memory, so the compiler can't just treat everything as a *value* that could be inlined - if it needs a location, it must be defined at namespace scope.

Comment: @Vincent I don't think your non array version is using the `operator()` (returns `Constant<double>` but `data` is `double` ). It is using the `Type()` conversion to convert to double.

Comment: @Named: The conversion operator is used *after* `operator()` has been invoked

Comment: @AndyProwl But `operator()` can not be called here. It should be an error. `data` is an array and the return expects `Constant<Type>`. No?

Comment: @Named: `pi` has type `Constant<Type>`, `Constant<Type>` has a `constexpr operator ()`, and the OP is doing `pi()`. It couldn't possibly mean anything else than an invocation of the call operator, and since the call operator is `constexpr`, this is legal - apart from the discussion of whether there should be a namespace scope definition of the `pi` data member, but that's another story

Comment: @AndyProwl I think I finally wrapped my head around it :) Took long enough. operator () is constructing a new Constant from data and returning it hmmm. Thanks.